# Identify lawn weed with bulbous root

Tags: identification, lawn, weeds

What is the name of this weed and what is the best way to get rid of it. Finding them in my lawn. Based in South Africa[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice first post, thank you for the details and photos. If you could add a locale (roughly should be enough), that might help the users here to answer your question.

Comment: That is a huge bulb!

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, that really helped. Thanks for the guidance on how to improve my post Stephie All the best for 2023

Answer (score 2):

That is an impressive tuber! From an online search it looks like *Guilleminea densa* (Small Matweed). See [here](http://southwestdesertflora.com/WebsiteFolders/All_Species/Amaranthaceae/Guilleminea%20densa,%20Small%20Matweed.html) and [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1437418869912482/posts/3128871614100524/?paipv=0&eav=AfairltlvoZwE8LgcIrlQiQNTxfVy-ZwwL3-8NHP-kXJvVGa2jAjv3LbrRvZONGmsMY&_rdr), for example.